# QScrollArea и компоновка виджетов

Tags: c++, qt

Есть `QScrollArea` и на нее нужно положить несколько виджетов.
Если сразу положить на нее layout, тогда все адекватно отображается, но ничего не скроллится(не появляются скролл бары, а виджеты просто уезжают за границы экрана).
Код: 
    QVBoxLayout* mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout(this);
    QScrollArea* scroll = new QScrollArea;
    mainLayout->addWidget(scroll);

```
QVBoxLayout* l = new QVBoxLayout;
scroll->setLayout(l);

QLabel* lbl = new QLabel;
lbl->setAlignment(Qt::AlignRight);
lbl->setText("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diem nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut lacreet dolore magna aliguam erat volutpat.");

l->addWidget(lbl);

QLabel* lbl1 = new QLabel;
lbl1->setAlignment(Qt::AlignLeft);
lbl1->setText("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diem nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut lacreet dolore magna aliguam erat volutpat."); 

l->addWidget(lbl1);
```

}

[image: Вывод]

А если добавить туда сначала виджет, в который засунуть layout, на который уже класть виджеты, тогда все скроллится, но виджеты не отображаются или отображаются криво(обрезанными).

Код:

```
QVBoxLayout* mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout(this);
scroll = new QScrollArea;
mainLayout->addWidget(scroll);

QWidget* ScrollAreaWidgetContents = new QWidget;
QVBoxLayout* ScrollLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
ScrollAreaWidgetContents->setLayout(ScrollLayout);
scroll->setWidget(ScrollAreaWidgetContents);

QLabel* lbl = new QLabel;
lbl->setAlignment(Qt::AlignRight);
lbl->setText("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diem nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut lacreet dolore magna aliguam erat volutpat.");

ScrollLayout->addWidget(lbl);

QLabel* lbl1 = new QLabel;
lbl1->setAlignment(Qt::AlignLeft);
lbl1->setText("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diem nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut lacreet dolore magna aliguam erat volutpat.");

ScrollLayout->addWidget(lbl1);
```

[image: Вывод]

Как решить данную проблему?

Answer (score 0):

Да поможет вам строчка:

```
    scroll->setWidgetResizable(true);
```